# Exception: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.2: ' ' is not a valid value for integer

Tags: xml, well-formed

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<departments>
<department>
    <deptid>1</deptid>
    <dname>Sales</dname>
    <employee>
        <empid>1001</empid>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <salary>20000</salary>
        <email>tom@gmail.com</email>
        <phoneno>9874563210</phoneno>
    </employee>
</department>
<department> <!--deptid and dname for some coloums are empty-->
   <deptid></deptid>
   <dname></dname>
    <employee>
        <empid>1002</empid>
        <name>Sam</name>
        <salary>25000</salary>
        <email>sam@gmail.com</email>
        <phoneno></phoneno>
    </employee>
</department>
<department>
   <deptid></deptid>
   <dname></dname>
    <employee>
        <empid>1003</empid>
        <name>Shiny</name>
        <salary>20000</salary>
        <email></email>
        <phoneno>9876543210</phoneno>
    </employee>
</department>
<department>
    <deptid>2</deptid>
    <dname>Admin</dname>
    <employee>
        <empid>1006</empid>
        <name>Ram</name>
        <salary>15000</salary>
        <email>ram@gmail.com</email>
        <phoneno>9873214560</phoneno>
    </employee>
</department>
<department>
   <deptid></deptid>
   <dname></dname>
    <employee>
        <empid>1007</empid>
        <name>Gupta</name>
        <salary>17000</salary>
        <email></email>
        <phoneno>9632587410</phoneno>
    </employee>
</department>
```

> Exception: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for
>   'integer'.

Contains employee details of five employees. I tried to document a well formed xml but I am getting error each time i execute it, Please help me with it.

[image: employee details]

I have mentioned the root element as departments and subsequently other elements.

Comment: Where is your DTD?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I have not posted it here since its giving the same error with or without it.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE departments
[
<!ELEMENT departments (department)>
<!ELEMENT department (deptid,dname,employee)>
<!ELEMENT deptid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT dname (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT employee (empid,name,salary,email,phoneno)>
<!ELEMENT empid (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT salary (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT email (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT phoneno (#PCDATA)>
]>

Comment: @Ravi Rishie can you answer it?

Comment: You are missing `</departments>`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Included. But same error.

Answer (score 1):

try putting some values over there instead of leaving them empty, i.e:

```
<phoneno>0</phoneno>
<email>nil</email>
```

it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

cvc-datatype-invalid is an XML Schema validation error, so for starters we need to see your schema. Also the message should include a line number which is always useful for diagnosis. My guess would be that the schema says deptid must be an integer, and if that's the case then your instance is obviously invalid for the reason stated in the error message.

Comment: How can i make it valid?

Comment: Do you want to change the schema or change the instance?